# Neo4j 2.2, passwords, and ROR error - Neography::UnauthorizedError in UsersController#try_login

Tags: neo4j, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just upgraded from 2.1 to 2.2.. Was prompted to add a password to neo4j.. Did that... graph looks fine.. but now my rails app, which uses the Neography Gem, won't connect.

I get this error:

Neography::UnauthorizedError in UsersController#try_login

I've changed the code to

```
@neo = Neography::Rest.new("http://neo4j:neo4j!@localhost:7474")
```

and it doesn't work.

Changed the initialization file to

```
Neography.configure do |config|
  config.protocol       = "http://"
  config.server         = "localhost"
  config.port           = 7474
  config.directory      = ""  # prefix this path with '/' 
  config.cypher_path    = "/cypher"
  config.gremlin_path   = "/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script"
  config.log_file       = "neography.log"
  config.log_enabled    = false
  config.max_threads    = 20
  config.authentication = nil  # nil 'basic' or 'digest'
  config.username       = "neo4j"
  config.password       = "neo4j!"
  config.parser         = MultiJsonParser
end
```

That doesn't work either  (don't worry passwords are changed)

Previously I never used a password with Neo, but with this new release I am, and now my app won't connect.  I do not have any certs installed and I'm using any form of authentication..

I can connect to the web admin after logging in with the correct password, but I just can't successfully connect via my app.

Is there something I've overlooked?  Do I need to install a cert?  Working on OS X 10.7.5, Rails 3.2.11, Ruby ruby 1.9.3p429, webrick, and the Neography Gem.

UPDATE:  I ran this from the rails console:

```
@neo = Neography::Rest.new("http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474")
```

and got back

```
=> #<Neography::Rest:0x007fe04a8ff9d0 @connection=#<Neography::Connection:0x007fe04a8ff7f0 @protocol="http://", @server="localhost", @port=7474, @directory="", @cypher_path="/cypher", @gremlin_path="/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script", @log_file="neography.log", @log_enabled=false, @max_threads=20, @parser=MultiJsonParser, @user_agent={"User-Agent"=>"Neography/1.0.9"}, @authentication={:basic_auth=>{:username=>"neo4j", :password=>"neo4j"}}, @client=#<HTTPClient:0x007fe04a906640 @proxy=nil, @no_proxy=nil, @no_proxy_regexps=[], @www_auth=#<HTTPClient::WWWAuth:0x007fe04a906438 @basic_auth=#<HTTPClient::BasicAuth:0x007fe04a906410 @cred=nil, @set=false, @auth={}, @challengeable={}, @scheme="Basic">, @digest_auth=#<HTTPClient::DigestAuth:0x007fe04a906118 @auth={}, @challenge={}, @set=false, @nonce_count=0, @scheme="Digest">, @negotiate_auth=#<HTTPClient::NegotiateAuth:0x007fe04a906050 @auth={}, @auth_default=nil, @challenge={}, @scheme="Negotiate", @set=false, @ntlm_opt={:ntlmv2=>true}>, @ntlm_auth=#<HTTPClient::NegotiateAuth:0x007fe04a905f38 @auth={}, @auth_default=nil, @challenge={}, @scheme="NTLM", @set=false, @ntlm_opt={:ntlmv2=>true}>, @sspi_negotiate_auth=#<HTTPClient::SSPINegotiateAuth:0x007fe04a905e48 @challenge={}, @scheme="Negotiate">, @oauth=#<HTTPClient::OAuth:0x007fe04a905d80 @config=nil, @auth={}, @challengeable={}, @nonce_count=0, @signature_handler={"HMAC-SHA1"=>#<Method: HTTPClient::OAuth#sign_hmac_sha1>}, @scheme="OAuth">, @authenticator=[#<HTTPClient::OAuth:0x007fe04a905d80 @config=nil, @auth={}, @challengeable={}
```

I then tried to create a node:

```
@neo.create_node
```

and received

```
Neography::UnauthorizedError:  from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/connection.rb:181:in `handle_4xx_500_response'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/connection.rb:143:in `return_result'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/connection.rb:126:in `evaluate_response'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/connection.rb:45:in `post'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/rest/nodes.rb:48:in `create_empty'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/rest/nodes.rb:35:in `create'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/neography-589bd7b680ac/lib/neography/rest.rb:81:in `create_node'
from (irb):2
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird... works for me.

```
2.2.0 :003 > @neo = Neography::Rest.new("http://neo4j:swordfish@localhost:7474")

@neo.create_node

{"extensions"=>{}, "outgoing_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out", "labels"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/labels", "traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/traverse/{returnType}", "all_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}", "self"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0", "property"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties/{key}", "properties"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties", "outgoing_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}", "incoming_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in", "create_relationship"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships", "paged_traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}", "all_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all", "incoming_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}", "metadata"=>{"id"=>0, "labels"=>[]}, "data"=>{}}
```

Can you check that you don't have "Neography::Rest.new" anywhere else in your code?

Comment: See my update above.. doesn't work.. Yes I have tons of Neography::Rest.new lines of code.. but this won't even work from the console..

Comment: Wonder if it's similar to this problem:  https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/issues/83

Comment: also changed this line in initialization file to   config.authentication = 'basic' and reloaded console still no conection

Comment: Hold on. The neo4j/neo4j one will never work. You are forced to change the password to something else.  Connect to the server via browser, change the password to swordfish, bring up IRB and try it again.

Comment: didn't work.. password is swordfish .. same problems

Comment: Seems like the issue is neography::unauthorizederror

Answer (score 0):

You could allow access without authentication (although this is of course less secure).

Change

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
```

to

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

in the file

```
conf/neo4j-server.properties
```